# How to convert tabs to spaces and auto formatting on save in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I would like know the steps for converting tabs to 4 spaces and auto formatting the java code on Save which is similar to eclipse.

In Eclipse I used to do the settings

For Converting tabs to Spaces I used to do the below setting

**Open references-> Java->Code style -> Formatter->Create a new profile-> Change the setting from tabs only to Spaces only**

To format the entire Java code of that particular file on save I used to do the below settings in Eclipse

**Open preferences-> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions->Check the appropriate options in the dialog**

But I don't aware to do the similar settings in Android Studio, can anyone help me to setup this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Auto Formatting your Java/xml files in Android Studio use following commands:

> CTRL + ALT + L

If you are using ubuntu , using this command will Log you out, use :

> Shift + CTRL + ALT + L

A popUp will appear : select whole file and Rearrange code and You are done. :)

**Update :**

As you are looking for a single point to go with your work as `eclipse` did, there is no such built in functionality in `Android studio` but it gives you the ability to do it through `Macro`, Follow these steps:

1. In studio open any of your source code file.
2. Press `Ctrl + Alt + O` This is used to find/optimize unused import. If a dialog open select 'Dont show it again' and hit Run.
3. Go to Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording.
4. Press `Ctrl + Alt + O`.
5. Press `Ctrl + Alt + L`. This formats your code. (`Shift+ctrl+Alt+L` for ubuntu).
6. Press `Ctrl + S` ,This saves your file;)
7. Go to Edit > Macros > Stop Macro Recording.
8. Save this created macro with name for instance:“Auto Formatting".

Boom, You have now successfully created your Macro, Now just add/assign a shortcut to it:

1. Open Preferences.
2. Search in the left bar for Keymap.
3. In the right hand pane, click in the search bar and type the name of your saved macro("Auto Formatting".)
4. Double click on your item. There might be two, it doesn’t matter which one you click on.
5. Click Add Keyboard Shortcut.
6. Set your keyboard shortcut to `Ctrl + S`.
7. Finally,Confirm overriding `Ctrl + S` to be your new macro.

That's it! your done man. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi @Anurag Pandit The solution which you have given is very good for me and with this I need to align manually every time after code has changed but I need **automated alignment** after written the code and saved it immediately.

Comment: @BKumar I have updated my answer , hopefully you will hit the shot now.:)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tip. It's really helpful

Comment: @Rinav Really appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

## Convert tab into spaces and vice versa

Type in `spac` in the search panel of the settings view.

Here you will find a shortcut to `Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Tabs and Indents -> Use tab character`

## AutoIndent

Simply `CTRL + ALT + L`

Comment: Hi @Pier Giorgio Misley I can able to convert tabs to spaces it's great but I need to auto align(Format) the code when I typed some code and save, how should I do that.

Comment: @BKumar this is the "AutoIndent".. ctrl + alt + L and it format the page you are using

Answer (score 0):

In the former replay just replace

1. Open Preferences
   *with*
   ***"Open the keymap settings, click File > Settings > Keymap (on Mac, File > Properties > Keymap)."***